# php - перевести количество дней прошедших с 1 января 1900 года в дату

Tags: php, время

Как перевести количество дней прошедших с 1 января 1900 года в дату ?
Например как понять, что 43344 - это 01.09.2018 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитесь читать документацию, там есть практически все примеры. Для вашей задачи есть класс [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php). В этом классе есть метод [add](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php), в который можно передавать объект класса [Dateinterval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php). В конструктор класса Dateinterval можно передавать всяческие значения, одним из которых и является количество дней:

```
$days = 43344;

$date = new DateTime('1900-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval("P{$days}D"));

echo $date->format('d.m.Y'); // 03.09.2018
```

---

Длительности определяют количество прошедшего времени во временном интервале и представляются в формате:

```
P: период
Y: годы
M: месяцы
D: дни
T: время
H: часы
M: минуты
S: секунды
```

Например:

```
DateInterval('P1D');     // 1 день
DateInterval('P2W');     // 2 недели
DateInterval('P3M');     // 3 месяца
DateInterval('P4Y');     // 4 года
DateInterval('P1Y1D');   // 1 год + 1 день
DateInterval('P1DT12H'); // 1 день + 12 часов
DateInterval('PT3600S'); // 3600 секунд
```